# Android: How to display a widget over another one using ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-view, android-constraintlayout

I use a `ConstraintLayout` and I have three widgets: a `View` (which is a simple line that matches parent in width and that is 1dp height), and two `FloatingActionButton`.  These two must be displayed over the `View` and vertically centered with the latter. I will use margins to separate them. My question is: how to display a widget over another one **using ConstraintLayout**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood your question. You can use `FrameLayout` or `ConstraintLayout` solution.

This is my solution using **`FrameLayout`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|start"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Result:

[image: result]

This is my solution using **`ConstraintLayout`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|start"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="84dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="84dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="84dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="84dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Result:

[image: result]

You can use different marings/padding to suit your needs.

**Don't forget to add `implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'` to your `build.gradle(Module:app)` file.**

Comment: In fact, there is no link between the FloatingActionButton and the View? Only between them and the ConstraintLayout?

Comment: Yes, there is no constraint between the View and the FABs.

Answer (score 2):

as grrigore already answered question perfectly, I want to point out:

**The sequence of widgets tag in layout xml files is important, the latter one will overlap the prior one, to avoid this, you could add  `android:background` attribute to prior widget to denoting this is a background.**